# How to OpenID: required fields and user mapping

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, openid

I would like to enable users of my we application to be able to login and register easier without remembering their credentials.

The purpose is to **make it easier for users** to start interacting with the application.

With the current registration the mandatory fields are: email, password and name.

I think about using OpenID (or even OAuth, which ATM I don't really need).

But I have a number of issues that I am not sure how to deal with:

1. If OpenID provider will not return **required fields** (email, name), how to proceed with registration (it's no longer simple and will envolve **more than 1 step**)?
2. How to map same user logging in using **another OpenID**? (`add openid` at SO) transparently?

I know about RPX, but don't want to rely on another intermediate 3rd for authentication.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do #2 transparently, since you don't know which OpenIDs belong to the same person unless they explicitly tell you (using a mechanism like "add openid")

Comment: Implicit mapping should often be possible as some of the datails are the same for all OpenId providers. One example may be email, whihc is likely to be same between Google, Facebook. The problem is that it is not possible to always implicitly dot it this way as email is different for other provider (yahoo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), it's really depend on how much information you required for an account to be considered registered. For example, Stack Overflow doesn't request any information from IdP; it simply assign a random username (user12345) - user would then complete it's personal information (and earn a badge) whenever she/he feels comfortable.

Not the that it's the best practice as users won't benefit from linking the accounts by avoiding enter her/his name twice. Again, it's really depend on what you really want to know about the user and how much fiction you are will to put in to the sign up process to get these info.

For (2) it's even a bigger issue. IMO the *add OpenID* feature at Stack Overflow is clear enough to tell people what it does. You may aggressively prompt user when you have detected that two OpenIDs returns the same e-mail address, but I am not sure if it's a good idea and good UX.

It is advised to separate username/userid of your site from OpenID though - small OpenID IdPs might close someday and you really don't what your users not being able to login because of it.

Comment: As for (1) - I explicitly mentioned the required fields in my question. And if you are suggesting to fill email randomly, I cannot do it for obvious reasons, though I possibly can for name. Is it what you propose as an answer for Q1?

I am not sure about the suggestion you are giving for the question (2)? Are you saying that any sign-in should be a new user (if no such exists) so that all OpenID accounts should be linked manually?

Comment: IdPs may not return the required fields even if your marked them as required. Do you want to reject users coming from these IdPs? If not, you still need to create an account for these user and ask for user info later.

Comment: As of (2), detecting e-mail address could work (e.g. "We have detected there is another account using the same e-mail. Is that you? If so we could merge these two accounts for you") And it's definitely a good practice to allow users to link multiple OpenIDs to the same user account coz it's possible one of the IdPs could out of service some day.

Comment: Clarification: For (1) I suggest fill the name with random value, asking user to fill the info later, just like what StackOverflow do with new sign-ups.

Comment: I don't worry about random name in (1), but rather email. No way I could fill it in randomly.